# Style-less win32 child window sizing

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, hwnd, childwindow

I have a win32 window that I need to put inside a WPF window.

That win32 window is NOT constructed as a child window initially.

```
var style = (SetWindowLongFlags)GetWindowLong(_hwnd, WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_STYLE);
            style &= ~(SetWindowLongFlags.WS_POPUP|SetWindowLongFlags.WS_CAPTION);
OR // style &= ~(SetWindowLongFlags.WS_BORDER);
            style |= SetWindowLongFlags.WS_CHILD;

SetWindowLong(_hwnd, WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_STYLE, style);

SetParent(_hwnd, hwndParent.Handle);
```

All is fine until I try to actually size the child window, with either `MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos`. It will just draw on the full height of the parent window and ignore height (and width) parameters. Positioning seems alright.

I have also tried the following approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-win32-control-in-wpf (with small modifications, as I don't create the win32 window myself so cannot give it `WS_CHILD` from the beginning) and with no styling I don't get the `SIZE` messages. If I create it myself as a child window from the start, then all is fine.

Any idea why removing the `WS_BORDER` or `WS_POPUP` styles from a window prevent me from resizing it?

Comment: Try adding the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style to the parent.

Comment: Already there. The parent window has:
PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_EX_STATICEDGE | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_EX_APPWINDOW | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_EX_LAYERED | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_CAPTION | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_MAXIMIZE | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_CLIPCHILDREN | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | PInvoke.User32.SetWindowLongFlags.WS_VISIBLE